# Manage tab activity with fragments from another classes

Tags: java, android, class, android-fragments

I have A fragment in another class and i want to launch it from my tab activity (which Google provide directly):

Here's the part of my FragmentActivity that control fragments, i don't want the dummy one but the one i created in another class

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.

                    // Here is my fragment
        Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase();
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase();
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And here is my MyFragment :

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

public Search() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setText("search page");
    return textView;
}
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the answer is simple :

```
public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.setText("search page");
return textView;
}
```

is not a real method, i don't even know why Eclipse gave me this when i created the class.

The real method is :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setText("search page");
    return textView;
}
```

This is just a problem of parameters.